# Showing li based on device not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap responsive utility to show and hide li
For `xs` `sm` and `md` first li shoud be hidden and for `lg` and `xl` first li shoud be visible but this is not working.
currently both are visible in all devices.

My code is below

```
<ul>
  <!-- For non mobile device it should be visible-->
  <li class="hidden-md-down">
    <a href="friends">
      <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- For mobile device it should be visible-->
  <li class="hidden-lg-up">
    <a href="mobilefriends">
      <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to make it working?

Comment: What Version  Bootstrap  Your are useing ?

Comment: I am using bootstreap 3.6 but I followed document of bootstreap4

Comment: SO YOu need to follow Bootstrap 3 document  Or You need to Use Bootstarp 4 .
Also You can see my answer .

Comment: I want to use bootstreap 3.6

Comment: so have some solution for it , Just use `hidden-xs` for desktop and `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` for Mobile . 
You need to check My Q Answer. Hare also You will be get example with Solution .. Check under .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code are Bootstrap **v4-alpha.** version . 
So At first confirm it What version are you use?
you can start Quick Bootstrap **v4-alpha.** BY CDN LINK..
Just add This two link .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Also if you want To use Bootstrap 3 .
You need use

`hidden-xs` For Only Desktop View

`hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`  **For Only Mobile View**

[More details link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/amsnezhn/2/)

Comment: @xrcwrn Check My answer .

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged your question using `twitter-bootstrap-3` you may use the [bootstrap 3 responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes). For example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="hidden-md">Mobile</li>
  <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Desktop</li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNvQbV)

If you are using `bootstrap-v4-alpha` you can of course use the [new responsive utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes) like `.hidden-md-down`, which should work fine:

```
<ul>
  <li class="hidden-md-up">Mobile</li>
  <li class="hidden-sm-down">Desktop</li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQXEay)

Comment: I was reading v4 document and I am working with 3.6 so that was creating problem. :)

Comment: Thats what I thought ;)